# Is it possible to use jQuery to grab the HTML of another web page into a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate with the FireShot API to given a URL, grab HTML of another web page into a div then take a screenshot of it.

Some things I will need to do after getting the HTML

- grab `<link>` & `<script>` from `<head>`
- grab `<body>` into `<div>`

But 1st, it seems when I try to do a

```
$.get("http://google.com", function(data) { ... });
```

I get a 200 in firebug colored red. I think it has to do with sites not allowing you to grab their page with JS? Then is opening a window the best I can do? But how might I control the other page with jQuery or call fsapi on that page?

**UPDATE**

I tried to do something like below to do something when the new window is ready, but FireBug says "Permission denied to access property 'document'"

```
w = window.open($url.val());
setTimeout(function() { // if I dont do this, I always get about:blank, is there a better way around this?
    $(w.document).ready(function() {
        console.log(w.document.body);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: As several people have answered, this is explicitly disallowed by web browsers.  Javascript can not be used to access content on different domains.  Browsers not only block these attempts when made via Ajax, but they also block attempts of javascript code to read the contents of other frames or windows if those contain content from other domains.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the cross-site security setup within Javascript is basically blocking this. You'd likely have to proxy the content through your own domain.

There are a couple other options I think for break the cross-site security constraints, but I'm not sure I'd promote them.

Answer (score 2):

If the "another page" locates within the same domain of your hosting page, yes, you can. Please refer to jQuery's `$().load()` API.

Otherwise, you're disallowed to do so by the browser's Cross-Site Security Policy. At this moment, you can choose to use iFrame instead of DIV.

Some jQuery plugins, e.g. thickbox provides ability to load pages to appropriate container automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am correct, I do not believe you can AJAX a page cross domain (e.g. from domain1.com to domain2.com). To get around this, you can have a PHP "proxy" script that does the "getting" of the page and then pass it to JS.

For example, in JS you would get() http://mydomain.com/get/?domain=http://google.com and then do what you need to do!

Comment: Hmm I think thats 1 option, I am thinking it will be best just to use JS if possble, that will be much faster